# S3 Deny Policy is not working for IAM Role

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a client who wants to give a bucket specific folders access to either root user or EMR_DefaultRole.

So, I have created a bucket policy which contains the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "DenyAllExceptRoot",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyPolicyS31",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::031342435657:role/EMR_DefaultRole",
                    "arn:aws:iam::031342435657:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bucket-singapore-1/test/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But, this bucket policy is not allowing my IAM role to delete the folder test's contents.

I have used action: Deny and NotPrincipal.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are bucket and roles in the same account ? If no, you need to create a Allow statement for them as well in the bucket policy, other wise you can try to add a bucket policy with allow statement and with condition                                "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "111111111111"
          ], you can add role as well in the condition.

Comment: Yes both are in the same account. So, How can I add role in the condition of bucket policy? @JamesDean

Comment: Like this: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "DenyAllExceptRoot",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyPolicyS31",
            "Effect": “deny”,
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [“*”]
                                },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod-bucket-singapore-1/test/*"       
             
            "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            “Role-arn”,
            “Rootarn”
          ]
        }
      }


        }
    ]
}

Comment: What can i put in place of Rootarn? It is arn:aws:iam::account-id:root? @JamesDean

Comment: "arn:aws:iam::031342435657:root"